# Can I sync the contents of one folder across multiple computers with Google Drive?

Tags: sync, google-drive-for-desktop

Say I have a folder "WORK STUFF" with various documents on it.

I would like this folder to appear on the Desktop of two different computers.

Further, I would like to set it up such that changing a document in WORK STUFF on computer one also changes that document in WORK STUFF on computer two.

Is that possible with Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Google Drive for Desktop is available for Mac and Windows. To learn more go to [Use Google Drive for Desktop](/https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10838124?hl=en)